# MS CRM 4 - Get queue that a case assigned to

Tags: queue, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am looking for a solution to my problem.  Is there a way to grab the value of the queue that a user assigns a case to on the case form.  I would like to add the queue name to a custom attribute for further use during the save.  I am using CRM 4 enterprise

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1):

Create an ASP.NET page which in it's URL takes the ticket ID and either:

1. Shows what you want to show. Embed that using an IFRAME
2. returns XML. You can then parse that using JavaScript in the Form Onload event and assign it to a field. Have a look at the duplicate detection sample for an example of this.

How does the ASP.NET page get that? You need to call the web service and query the queue items entity for queue item which has a item id matching your ticket. Then check the queue id property to get the queue.